# Grid view Edit issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have editable grid view, If I click on edit in any row say "x", it opens in edit mode, however if I click on any other row, say "y", "x" should cancel edit. But In my code after clicking on "y", both the rows remains in edit mode.

```
protected void gvViewAdmins_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gvViewAdmins.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

    Label lblEmailId = gvViewAdmins.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("gvlblEmail") as    Label;
    lblEmailId.Visible = false;
    ViewState["currentEmailId"] = lblEmailId.Text;

    TextBox textboxEmailId = gvViewAdmins.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("gvtbEmailId") as TextBox;
    textboxEmailId.Text = ViewState["currentEmailId"].ToString();
    textboxEmailId.Visible = true;

    Label lblRole = gvViewAdmins.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("gvlblRole") as Label;
    lblRole.Visible = false;
    ViewState["currentRole"] = lblRole.Text;

    DropDownList dropdownRoles = gvViewAdmins.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("gvddlRoles") as DropDownList;
    this.PopulateRole(dropdownRoles);
    dropdownRoles.Visible = true;
    this.SelectRoleDropDownValue(dropdownRoles);

    LinkButton lbtnUpdate = gvViewAdmins.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("lbtnUpdate") as LinkButton;
    LinkButton lbtnCancel = gvViewAdmins.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("lbtnCancel") as LinkButton;
    LinkButton lbtnEdit = gvViewAdmins.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("lbtnEdit") as LinkButton;

    lbtnUpdate.Visible = true;
    lbtnCancel.Visible = true;
    lbtnEdit.Visible = false;

}
```

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at your code, It seems that, you are not using gridview's default edit functionality. You are just setting controls visible property on and off.

Better way is, Define ItemTemplate and Edit Item Template Separately like,

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="objGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" onRowEditing="objGridView_RowEditing">
  <columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lblEmailID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("<<EmailID Field>>")%>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("<<EmailID Field>>")%>'/>
        </EditItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
  </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void objGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
  objGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
  <<BindGrid Again>>
}
```

Comment: Ok now I changed my code as per your sample. However There is one drop down list which will be seen only in edit mode. If I keep it in <EditItemTemplate>, Code for findControl does not work in code behind. `DropDownList dropdownRoles = gvViewAdmins.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("gvddlRoles") as DropDownList;
        this.PopulateRole(dropdownRoles);
        dropdownRoles.Visible = true;
        this.SelectRoleDropDownValue(dropdownRoles);` Here drop down shows null value while debugging.

Comment: I got it...I have to findcontrol in PreRender Event and not in Row Edititng...Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You can find control in row databound event also, by checking if(e.Row.RowIndex == gvViewAdmins.EditIndex){DropDownList dropdownRoles = gvViewAdmins.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("gvddlRoles") as DropDownList}, which checks currently binding row is the editing row. And, another thing, there is no need to write "dropdownRoles.Visible = true; ". It'll display it anyway.